# Why does my website need to reload to work properly

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have a problem regarding my express.js server.
I'm hosting my webpage locally with port 3000.

On my website I have a function that's used to register/login a user. Once you start the server, the URL looks like this: http://localhost:3000/
If my URL looks like that and I try to register/login, my website only reloads.

After the failed registration/login and the reload, the URL changes to the following: http://localhost:3000/?# When the URL looks like this, the registration/login works perfectly fine.

My registration function looks like this:

```
async function onRegisterSubmit() {
obj = {
    username: document.getElementById("username").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    password: document.getElementById("password").value
}
if (validation(obj)) {
    return;
}

const body = JSON.stringify(obj);
const res = await fetch("/register", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: body
});

if (res.status === 201) {
    alert("Registered succesfully.");
    closeForm();
} else {
    alert("There was an error.");
}}
```

My express.js /register looks like this:

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {  
if ( !req.body.email 
  || !req.body.password
  || !req.body.username 
  || typeof req.body.email !== 'string' 
  || typeof req.body.password !== 'string'
  || typeof req.body.username !== 'string'
) {
  res.sendStatus(400);
}
users.push({ email: req.body.email, passwordDerivative: encrypt(req.body.password), username: req.body.username });
lists.push({ username: req.body.username, lists: []})

res.status(201).send('Registered user with mail: ' + req.body.email);})
```

What is the problem here? How can I get my website to function properly without having to reload it first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I provided some code, let me know if that's helpful. If you need something else I can provide it.